# Why are my destination links only binding the last contact as the destination link's data?

Tags: swiftui, foreach, navigation

I am iterating through an array of Contacts to display a cell for each contact in a grid. Please see my code:

```
ForEach($contacts, id: \.self) { $contact in
                        // Creating a grid item for each contact
                        ContactCell(contact: contact)
                            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $shouldPresentContactMainView) {
                                ContactMainView(contact: $contact)
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                shouldPresentContactMainView.toggle()
                            }
                    }
```

What's weird is that, all of the grid items display the correct cell for each contact. However, when I tap on one of them, it segues, then displays the data of the last contact of the array... it doesn't matter if you tap on the first grid item, second, third, etc... all grid items will segue to the ContactMainScreen(with the same data here)

Why doesn't it send the data for the specific contact in the foreach loop?

Comment: You need a Bool for each row, you can achieve that by creating a sub view but it is likely simpler to just use a NavigationLink with value

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum. How would you do this with a subview? I am intentionally avoiding NavigationLink because, from my understanding, it creates a physical link that must be tapped on. I don't want any link. I just want to be able to tap anywhere in the cell. (Like a CollectionView)

Comment: See below for an answer, because of the `Binding` the new `NavigationLink` isn't an option. But without the binding the "Link" isn't visible the cell would be the label, the whole think is tappable.

Comment: Oh my bad, I guess I haven't refreshed my page since I last saw your comment. lol thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `@State` for each cell so adding the `navigationDestination` code to the `ContactCell` can be one way of dong this.

```
struct ContactCell: View{
    @Binding var contact: Contact
    @State var isPresenting: Bool = false
    var body: some View{
        Text(contact.name)
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
                ContactMainView(contact: $contact)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                isPresenting.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

You can also use a `ViewModifier`

```
struct ContactsListView: View {
    @State var contacts: [Contact] = (0...10).map { n in
        Contact(name: "\(n)")
    }
    var body: some View {
        LazyHGrid(rows: Array(repeating: .init(), count: 4)) {
            ForEach($contacts, id: \.id) { $contact in
                // Creating a grid item for each contact
                ContactCell(contact: contact)
                    .modifier(PresentViewModifier(contact: $contact))
            }
        }
    }
}
struct PresentViewModifier: ViewModifier{
    @State var isPresenting: Bool = false
    @Binding var contact: Contact
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresenting, destination: {
                ContactMainView(contact: $contact)
            })
            .onTapGesture {
                isPresenting.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```